# Object allocate and init in Swift

Tags: swift, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

In Objective-C, all memory allocation are took over by `malloc` function in libmalloc framework, but things are different in Swift.

For example:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
}
```

I've Google it for a long time but no luck. Can somebody tell me how memory is allocated behind the scenes in Swift?

Comment: Are you asking how memory is allocated behind the scenes? Or are you asking about how initialization/allocation is done in from the perspective of an app developer? [The Swift Programming Language: Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) covers the latter. I’m unclear what the question is...

Comment: @Rob yes, I am asking how memory is allocated behind the scenes, I will modify my question, sorry for that

Comment: The implementation is also open source... if you can find the bit that does this I think several people would be interested.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line where an object is instantiated, switch to Always Show Disassembly and step into the allocation functions. See [swift_allocObject_](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/HeapObject.cpp) and [swift_slowAlloc](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/Heap.cpp)

Comment: @Willeke Great! Very Useful!

Answer (score 0):

There are many helper function call did generate when compile. Eg: swift_allocObject.
If you interest this. You should download Hopper Disassembler app for analysis binary after compile to find this.